# Are single-sided forks a gimmick?

Tags: fork, cannondale

The first time I saw a Cannondale with a one-sided fork I was in shock & awe.

But I got to thinking about it, and it seems to me like it's just a marketing strategy, touting the quality and mechanical sophistication of the brand.

It saves some weight, maybe. But it loses *so* much strength. How could it possibly have a better strength/weight ratio than a traditional fork?

Comment: The lefty forks are generally used in events where weight matters more than overall strength.

Comment: I think a couple of Cannondale factory team races run a 160mm lefty on the Jekyll but a majority run a two legged fork.

Comment: How do you know it loses so much strength? Cannondale frames used to have a reputation for breaking but the lefty has never had one.

Comment: Lefty forks are not much lighter than their market competition i.e. Rock Shox SID or DT Swiss forks. Thus the amount of material used must be more or less the same. The innovative thing about it is putting both spring and damper in the same side. Plus it's one of few upside-down bicycle forks, and one of the first designed for cross-country. Personally I've never heard of broken Lefty forks (more often frames).

Comment: I think they're rare enough that the rep for breaking or not would be hard to come by.

Comment: Premise of the question maybe flawed - "It looses so much strength" - Show how you know this. (However I think you are right about the marketing. If there was a compelling advantage, others would be doing it even if it meant licensing IP from Cannondale.

Comment: Hey, what do I know. Maybe the one-sided forks are stronger because of really, really good engineering. But when you think about the physics of it, it's clear that you would need a phenomenally rigid connection to the side of your hub to give the wheel the same amount of of support as a traditional fork gives.

Comment: @OverOverUnderSkipAHole Actually, Lefty has its own hubs and wheel spindle integrated into the fork which allows for (apparently comparative stiffness as regular forks. Plus the fork is dual crown which increases stiffness from the top, so I wouldn't worry too much about it. I agree with the marketing argument though; Cannondale keeps introducing their own standards for everything hoping that it would be seen as being super innovative and be accepted as normal by the industry, but it's rarely the case.

Comment: ....need a phenomenally rigid connection to the side of ... - In that case, show how you know this.  Have a look at the stub axle on a car or truck and think about the forces it carries, then show me how you know a bicycle axle cannot be build strong and stiff enough for bicycle weights.

Comment: Mounting is actually easier since the axle doesn't have to be removable the way the axle on a conventional fork does. And fixing punctures is a breeze. Not that I'm a C'dale fan, but this particular idea is a good one - it must be, Mike Burrows had it first!

Comment: @mattnz Image holding a bicycle axle out in front of yourself at arm's length with both arms. That's the traditional bicycle fork. Now remove one hand. The pressure on the axle that you're able to resist (in all directions) has gone down vastly. Imagine how strong (and therefore heavy) your one arm would have to be to equal the stability given by both arms. I know Cannondale has optimized it, shortening the axle, integrating the hub into the fork. But the concept still stands, because the wheel is off to one side of the single arm.

Comment: @OverOverUnderSkipAHole: Imagine holding a car wheel out in front of yourself by one arm, and if you can, imagine doing it with a truck wheel - that is what every car, truck, trailer and most aeroplanes in the world use to hold wheels on. Few wheeled vehicles use a fork design.  Additionally some motorbikes (Dating back to the 1950's) have used the concept.

Comment: @mattnz Okay, I think I see where you're going. The axle's strength makes sense to me now. But I'm still not convinced of the single fork arm's ability to resist lateral pressure, and more importantly, twisting pressure.

Answer (score 4):

I think that their main point is not less weight but more control.  Imagine the normal 2-legged fork: even though the two sides are connected to the same air spring, you could concievably temporarily compress one more than the other, and now your front wheel is no longer pointed in the direction that the handlebars are.  This can only happen if the bridge is flexible, and typical fork bridges are very strong.

The Lefty avoids this by using a single stanchion, which can only move linearly, but now must be able to support twisting motion.  I do not know if Cannondale has succeeded in making it strong enough, but Leftys have been around for years, so it can't be too far off the mark.

And, note the many schemes for rear suspension.  There are many ways to suspend a bicycle; no single type is so good that all manufacturers must use it.  The same is apparently true for front suspension.

Comment: But with the single-legged fork the fork AND axle must be able to resist bending under (pretty extreme) load, producing even more of a problem than with the 2-legged fork and uneven compression.

Comment: @Daniel: Not sure the comparison works as the axle attachment on a single can be made orders of magnitude stronger. Consider a stub axle on car or aircraft landing gear - its effectively the same wheel attachment as a Lefty.

Comment: @mattnz - Among other things, the auto axle is balanced by the axle on the other side.  And the auto suspension is actually DESIGNED to "bend" (camber) as it compresses, to maintain the desired geometry.

Comment: @DanielRHicks The car camber works to compensate for inability of a car to lean on the turns, so it has no point on a bicycle. Also even in two-legged forks the spring is in one leg only, so compression is uneven anyway (if I got you right). Yes, the toher leg may work as a support, but if the system is stiff enough (and with 14 years on the market it proved so), there is no need to worry about its strength. and the imbalance caused by removing one leg is minimal - around 700g more to one side is negligible.

Comment: I'm impressed that Cannondale has made that fork as strong as it is, but couldn't you make a two-sided fork that's cheaper, stronger, and lighter?

Comment: DT Swiss manufactures a two-leg fork weighing around the same as the lightest Lefty. It's not much cheaper and works quite as fine. Rock Shox used to manufacture forks weighing just over 1kg, unfortunately their stiffness was rubbish. Looks like whether we use two legs or one, it's the limit for today's engineering.